# Add observer dynamic on dom-if element

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, observers, mutation-observers

1) If I want to select element on dom-if condition and run observer how can I achieve that scenario i.e I have dropdown which is wrapped inside dom-if and on page load some observer is changing flag to true,which trigger dom-if condition to render that dropdown,but the problem is when page loads I bind the options for dropdown in observer which get the element `this.$.elementID || this.$.querySelector('#elementID')` and binds it so I am not getting that element but in ui it shows blank dropdown without options so I guess element is not getting selected.

Please help?

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[flag]]" restamp="true">
    <dropdown id = "elementID"></dropdown>
</template>
```

JS:

```
properties:{
  list: {
   type: Array,
   notify: true,
   value: [{label:"f1",value:"f1"},{label:"f2",value:"f2"}]
  }
}

static get observers() {
    return [
      '_bindDrop(list)',
    ];
}

_bindDrop(list) {
  const select = this.$.querySelector('#elementID');
   if (select) {
    select.options.length = 0;
    list.forEach(function (item) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = item.label;
    option.value = item.value;
    select.appendChild(option);
   });
  }
 }
```

or

2) How to add dynamic observer method on an element in dom-if condition,if element gets flag to true then it adds observer method ?

Answer (score 0):

He an example add, remove options with `Polymer-2.x` :

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/ymoqWZ?editors=1011)

```js
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', () => {
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }
    
    static get properties() {
      return {
        selected:{type:String}, style:{type:String},
        list: {
          type: Array,
          value() {return  [{label:"f1",value:"f1", flag:false},{label:"f2",value:"f2", flag:true},{label:"f3",value:"f3", flag:true}] }
          
        }
      };
    }
    
    static get observers(){ return ['_toogleSelected(selected)', '_listChanged(list.*)']}
    
    _toogleSelected(s){      
      let objinx = this.list.findIndex(o => o.label === s);
      let obj = this.list[objinx]
      obj.flag = !obj.flag;
 
      this.set('list.'+objinx, obj)
      this.notifyPath('list.'+ objinx)

    }

    _styleIt(s) {
       return s? "green;":"red;";
    }
    _listChanged(l){
       console.log('List changed', l)
    }
  }
  customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/2.6.0.2/lib/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">  
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html"> 
  <link rel="import" href="iron-selector/iron-selector.html">   
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
     <paper-dropdown-menu label="Listed Items">
        <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" >
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]"  id="lists" mutable-data>
             <template is="dom-if" if="[[item.flag]]">
                <paper-item  >[[item.value]] - [[item.flag]]<paper-item>
             </template>

          </template>
        </paper-listbox>
     </paper-dropdown-menu>
          
          
     <div>Options display Toogle</div>
        <iron-selector attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{selected}}" >
           <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]" mutable-data>
              <button name="[[item.label]]" id="[[item.label]]" style="background-color:{{_styleIt(item.flag)}}"> [[item.value]]</button>
          </template>
        </iron-selector>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

Comment: yes the thing you did is true but i want solution in the way it is written and add dynamic observer to it

Comment: Its very easy, instead  filter in `dom-repeat`, you can use dom-if element. But this makes more code lines, that's why I did like this. I can change it very quick @TapanDave

Comment: @TapanDave Hey is it the way above that you looking for? (check the demo and above code. It's with the `observer`,  and `dom-if`)